# cant get token from openvidu-server with flask, SSLError appears

Tags: python, flask, openvidu

```
 class GetTokenApi(Resource):
     def get(self):
            openvidu = OpenVidu('https://localhost:4443/', 'MY_SECRET')
            session = openvidu.create_session()
            token = session.generate_token()
            return success_result({'token': token}), 200
```

after call of this api, shows "
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/sessions (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))"

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine you’re deploying OpenVidu with a self-signed certificate. You need to accept this self-signed certificate of openvidu-server the first time try to join a video-call.

You can read [how to start with OpenVidu](https://docs.openvidu.io/en/2.12.0/tutorials/openvidu-hello-world/) for more info.